# Connection between RPi and PIC

Tags: pic, raspberry-pi, protocol

Before I start I would like to say that I'm a complete novice with microcontrollers and would like to be treated as one and receive answers acordingly... more like "Q: How many legs does a human have? A: A human has two legs, one in the left, one in the right.", if you know what I mean. I know these questions may seem basic to some, but please, if you can, help me.

I recently started a project in which I have to make a connection between a RPi and a PIC32mx695f512h. Problem is... I don't even know how to start. All I know is that I need to write some protocols on both and that's it. So my questions are:

What protocols should I use?
How do I program the Pi?
How do I program the PIC?
How do I connect the two?
What software do I have to use for both?
I would like to use python for the Pi and C for the PIC. And I have a PICKit3 also. Any help would be useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Both are 3.3v I/O devices with asynchronous serial (UART) interfaces at comparable signaling voltages.  This would be a good choice for interconnecting them as it is simple and well supported by software on both ends.

Additionally, the PIC device has a USB OTG interface which could be configured in device mode and connected to one of the pi's USB peripheral ports.  This can allow higher data rates, but at the expense of substantially more complicated software (and, counterintuitively, longer delays in getting a response).

There are additional possibilities as well, such as SPI, I2C, etc - however these tend to be more obscure and are less likely to be used between to micrcoprocessor-type devices unless the other interfaces are already used up by other needs.  Additionally, it's hard to substitute your development PC for one end of the conversation (a *very* useful technique during software development) when using these interfaces.

You should be able to find many examples of serial and USB interfacing for both boards.  Without more detail of your requirement, these would be beyond the scope of your question here.